# Drools activation-group not work as expected

Tags: drools

rule "one"

```
activation-group "Harris"

salience 10

when

    $p : Person(age < 10);

then

    $p.setDiscount(0.1);
```

end

rule "two"

```
activation-group "Harris"

salience 10

when

    $p : Person(age > 10);

then

    $p.setDiscount(0.2);
```

end

When I insert some Persons to working memory through KSession.insert(Object), only the first Person is evaluated, the other persons just ignored. My understanding about Drools activation-group is that if I have X number of rules that belong to the same activation-group with various salience values that each 
Person will be processed by the rules and the one with the highest 
salience will be fired and the rest will be ignored.  Once that's 
complete the next Person will come through and repeat the process.  What 
I'm experiencing is that the first Person to trigger any rule in that 
activation-group will disable the entire activation group and no further 
Persons will be processed. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: In addition to laune answer below option a, if you don't need to perform joins with other rules on several `Person` instances, you could use a StatelessKieSession, executing for each given `Person` instance

Answer (score 1):

"Only one rule within an activation group will fire, i.e., the first one to fire cancels any existing activations of other rules within the same group." This is pretty explicit.

Don't use an activation group if you want to do the same thing for many Person facts.

(a) Insert just one, fire all rules - repeat.

(b) Insert many persons, fire all rules but retract a Person fact in each consequence.

Salience is almost always bad. Use logic (constraints) for fine-grained control of the rule firing order.

Comment: Thanks, now I used the method a , repeat insert one fact and fire, but I think  that is low performance. What the method  b is exactly? I add like       " retract($p)" for every rule RHS, but it's useless。

Comment: What makes you think that this is "low performance"? --- What do you mean by "it's useless"? Surely the fact does not remain in WM and fire more rules!?

Comment: I add " retract($p)" for every rule's RHS, but as before,only the first person fired, the rest just be ignored.

Comment: Did you omit the activation-group?

Answer (score 0):

**activation-group** will not work in your case. Insert and fireAlleules one by one shockingly that will work because it will fire up the rules considering the new updates in KnowledgeBase.(Not Recommended).

But i would suggest you to write up the unique rules to avoid **activation-group**. You can also try extending rules for more constructive.